# Error importing JSONL dataset into Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I tried importing a JSONL dataset into Google's Vertex AI and get a weird and seemingly unrelated error:

```
Error: Could not parse the line, json is invalid or the format does not match the input schema: Cannot find field: classificationAnnotation in message google.cloud.aiplatform.master.schema.ImageBoundingBoxIoFormat. for: gs://[bucketname]/set.jsonl line 10
```

It happens every 4 lines of code. All of my lines are identical except the image name changes.

Line 10:

```
{"imageGcsUri":"gs://[mybucket]/path/to/image.png","classificationAnnotation":{"displayName":"MyLabel","annotationResourceLabels":{"aiplatform.googleapis.com/annotation_set_name":"MyLabel"}},"dataItemResourceLabels":{"aiplatform.googleapis.com/ml_use":"training"}}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Hi Jared, did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

From the line you are sharing, it seems like the image you are trying to access doesn't exist in the bucket you are using, so you would need to see if the image is on the same name or format you are calling it.